# Where can I ask a question about sending mail to someone in specific country?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Questions about, how to mail something to a specific country, could they be accepted in Travel.SE?

Comment: Seems unlikely, but isn't this a questions to ask at [meta.travel.se]?

Comment: It's better to ask on Meta.travel. Or do some searches on either travel or meta travel. You would discover there is a mail tag http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail which suggest that such questions might belong there.